# Android Location Service broken when using tabs

Tags: android

I'm building an android application which uses gps to locate the user. I have a class called LocationService which extends Service and implements LocationListener. In my activity I have the following code. When I want to turn on the service and listen for locations, I call the startLocationService() method. All this is working fine.

I then put this activity in a tab in a tabhost. Now when I call startLocationService(), nothing happens, the onCreate() method in LocationService is not even called. I checked the "this" reference in the line 
Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationService.class); 
and it refers to the correct activity, not the TabActivity.

I'm at a loss to explain why LocationService is not being started. I'd appreciate any light anyone can shed on this.

thanks,
Paul

```
private LocationService service = null;
private ServiceConnection svcConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        service = (LocationService)binder;
        try {
            service.registerCallback(cbListener);
            service.enableProximityPoints();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("MyPath", "Exception in call to registerAccount()", t);
        }
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        service = null;
    }
};



private void startLocationService(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    bindService(i, svcConn, 0);
    startService(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone else has had a similar problem: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg08047.html

They solved their problem by moving the service connection up into the TabActivity class.

Comment: Just noticed I didn't select this as the correct answer, will do so now.

Answer (score 0):

> I checked the "this" reference in the
>   line Intent i = new Intent(this,
>   LocationService.class); and it refers
>   to the correct activity, not the
>   TabActivity.

That might well be the problem - I've found activities as contents of tabs behave slightly differently to what I expect sometimes.

In the activity which is the 'tab content' activity try defining a class instance member...

```
private Context parent = null;
```

Then in `onCreate()` ...

```
parent = this.getParent(); // Gets the TabActivity context
```

Then in `startLocationService()` use...

```
Intent i = new Intent(parent, LocationService.class);
```

Not sure if it will work but worth a try. I'm currently working on a TabActivity based app and I'm having to do things like this in various places in the 'tab content' activities to get things to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had to move all ServiceConnection code to the TabActivity, then it worked. (See the other reply)

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the confirmation (that it didn't work I mean). Worth noting for the future.